# No numbers in bibliography for moderncv

Tags: bibliographies, moderncv

So I'm using `moderncv` and for whatever reason whenever I try and add a bibliography, they all come back not numbered. Here's a MWE:

texfile:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
%\usepackage{multibib}


\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
    \bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

File  `biblio.bib`:

```
@book{abook,
    Title           = {Some Book},
    Author          = {Me},
    Publisher       = {A human},
    Year            = {2018},
}
```

This is giving me a bibliography, but it is not numbered at all. I tried different bibliography styles, and nothing. I also tried using `multibib` and nothing worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get numbered bibliography entrys you have to add the following line in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
```

Because there is an `@` used you have to enclose this line with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

With the following MWE (please see that I added the missing name):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{abook,
    Title           = {Some Book},
    Author          = {Me},
    Publisher       = {A human},
    Year            = {2018},
}
@article{einstein,
  author  = "Albert Einstein",
  title   = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
              [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal = "Annalen der Physik",
  volume  = "322",
  number  = "10",
  pages   =  "891--921",
  year    = "1905",
  DOI     = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}


\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
  \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: pdf result]

Comment: Do you know how to get the correct indentation? The format looks quite odd when the reference takes more than one line.

Comment: @Andreina I do not know what you mean, the indentation is correct in my eyes, see the updated answer. The red line before P in Publications in the screenshot shows you the starting point for printing references text. The label is per definition printed hanged, that means it is placed in the first column usualy used for dates of `\cventry` ...

Comment: I should have been more specific.  The indentation looked weird when I changed the style from classic to banking (it looks perfect using classic). I was able to easily modified the code in the other answer but not yours, which is why I added it as an alternative way.  Your suggestion looks simpler and cleaner so I tried it first.